# Handle ImageButtons with different image sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

My layout contains 3 ImageButtons, arranged vertical in a `LinearLayout`.

Now I want that each of them has the same height and together fill the device's screen height.

Works fine with the attribute `android:layout_weight="1"`. But if the image of one `ImageButton` is too big, it won't work (this button is higher than the others), despite setting `android:scaleType="center_inside"`.

Any advices/tricks?
If you need any code, let me know. But there is nothin special.

Comment: What are the values for `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`?

Comment: Both fill_parent for all buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have given weights correctly than this should work. The size of the image doesn't matter than. Just one thing to keep in mind while using weights is that attribute for which you are giving the weight(height/width) should be assigned value "0dp" in the xml, only then the weights will work correctly. Here is the example code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:gravity="center"
android:weightSum="3">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/drawable1"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/drawable2"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/drawable3"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Just use this xml and replace the drawables according to your needs. Let me know if any issues.

Comment: android:layout_height="0dp", nice :) Thanks a lot! :)